# jQuery UI Datepicker uuid bug?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm extending the datepicker in my code by resetting the `_generateHTML` function in `beforeShow`, i.e. `$.datepicker._generateHTML = function(a) { .. }`

This way I can do whatever I want to the buttons on the buttonpanel. Here's my example code: http://jsfiddle.net/benno_007/UjFEm/1/.

Sometimes the datepicker will work (i.e. click a date), sometimes it won't. This is because it takes > 1ms for my datepicker to generate, and as a result, the uuid is out by a millisecond. `window["DP_jQuery_" + z]` is initially set as 'z' and 'z' is what it used throughout the datepicker plugin for the onclick of the buttons. BUT, at the end of the plugin code, it sets `$.datepicker.uuid = new Date().getTime();` and because I extend the function, I have to get the `$.datepicker.uuid` to replace my `DP_jQuery{time}`.. but because it took so long to generate, its 1ms off, and then I can't do anything with the datepicker.

I'm going to fix this by replacing d.datepicker.uuid=(new Date).getTime() with d.datepicker.uuid=z in my local plugin code, but my real question is:

**Is this a bug in jQueryUI's datepicker, or is it by design?**

Comment: It's by design to allow multiple datepickers on the same page. You're getting into trouble because you're trying to override function which was meant to be private (it starts with underscore which is as you may know a common naming convention). It's not a bug since authors of datepicker didn't expect you to mess with "private" functions of their plugin.

Comment: Thanks, was thinking it had something to do with that. Although its weird, when I added two datepickers, they both had the same uuid and clicking the second one put the date in the first ones input box. Maybe I didn't do something right there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to WTK, it's by design (not a bug).

Just thought I'd close this post.